# Sent Bitcoins to an expired address - how do I get back?

Tags: lost-transactions

I sent bitcoins to my CampBX address, and I was unaware that addresses expired, and it had.  So I sent them, they were taken out of my account, and now they are gone...

How do I get them back?

Bitchain says they were sent - but they are not in either account:

https://blockchain.info/address/1aPb2GVC3YVcaRce17EAjEZL9ZsT1Ssqi

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm unsure why Camp BX began this practice.  Perhaps it helps to protect them by not retaining the link between the bitcoin deposited and the Camp BX exchange account that gets credited.  Or maybe there's some other reason.  I'm of the opinion thought that the funds should be recoverable for a longer period of time.   Maybe they allow it after filing a support ticket? https://campbx.kayako.com/Tickets/Submit

Answer (score 1):

From Camp BX:

"Do not use this address after the expiry date, as your Bitcoin transfers will not be credited to your account. If you mistakenly make a deposit to an expired address, our system administrator has to expend several hours to track it down. We have to bill these hours out to customer if they wish to recover a lost deposit."

Comment: I submitted a ticket - and am just waiting for a response.  It is only about $100 worth, so I was going to just say that they can keep 30% or something.  Does anyone know a phone # for them?

Answer (score 0):

CampBX are bound to keep the matching private keys somewhere. Otherwise they would lose quite some money as I'm sure you're not the only one who sends funds to an address that has "expired".

I believe the thing that expired was the binding between the funding address and your account. CampBX should be able to trace it though. A simple Support Ticket like Stephen suggested should resolve this situation.

Comment: Well, technically, they could have deleted those keys after expiring the address. It's not them that lost the money... Let's hope they still have them, though. Otherwise that's just irresponsible.

Comment: Yes, right. That "bound" in my answer is an opinion, but I assume that they are rational :-)